# drag drop clone help needed for web form builder with postback

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, postback, clone

I am noobe, and seeking and example/help on making a web form builder like woofoo, in jquery. Using your help, I plan to be able to extend this to other icons/image/controls/packaged DIV content.

**Can you please show me how to clone HTML elements from a drag, drop and post it back to the server.**

1. Cloning/Sorting HTML elements via drag n drop in jquery and Jquery UI. (and subsequently extend to some nested div containers elements), with edit text
2. Next, capturing the HTML and posting back the HTML/DIV content
3. Bootstrap Themeable

With little success, I have been looking at this minikomi/Bootstrap-Form-Builder
http://minikomi.github.io/Bootstrap-Form-Builder, I'm finding this hard to follow or extend with ASP MVC.

I broke down the code to the JS templating, backbone, but getting lost after the require.js, the templating is hard to understand, can someone break it down, or give me an alternate example please

optionally, the end postback has to be captured in ASP MVC

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the same thing and I came across this example: http://www.anupshinde.com/form-builder-part-2

It is a simple example that should get you started with it. Also follow the documentation for draggable - droppable on [JqueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) website.